# Google Apps Script: Outgoing webhook not being sent after adding a row to Google Sheet on incoming request

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm facing an issue with my Google Apps Script project. I want my code to perform two tasks:

1. Add a new row with data from the incoming request to the corresponding columns of a Google Sheet.
2. Send an outgoing webhook to a specific URL after the row is successfully added.

I have written code that successfully adds a new row to the sheet upon receiving an incoming request, but the webhook is not being sent automatically. If I manually run the webhook sending function in the script editor, the webhook is sent successfully.

Here's my code:

```
const SPREADSHEET_ID = "ID";
const SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";
const LOGS_SHEET_NAME = "Logs";
const WEBHOOK_URL = "URL";

function doGet(e) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  logToSheet("Incoming request: " + JSON.stringify(e.parameter));

  const newRowData = [
    e.parameter.date,
    e.parameter.user_id,
    e.parameter._ga,
    e.parameter.utm_source,
    e.parameter.utm_medium,
    e.parameter.utm_campaign,
    e.parameter.utm_term,
    e.parameter.utm_content,
  ];

  sheet.appendRow(newRowData);
  logToSheet("New row added: " + JSON.stringify(newRowData));

  sendWebhook(WEBHOOK_URL, newRowData);

  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Data successfully added and sent.");
}

function sendWebhook(url, newRowData) {
  const payload = {
    date: newRowData[0],
    user_id: newRowData[1],
    _ga: newRowData[2],
    utm_source: newRowData[9],
    utm_medium: newRowData[10],
    utm_campaign: newRowData[11],
    utm_term: newRowData[12],
    utm_content: newRowData[13],
  };

  const options = {
    method: "post",
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
  };

  logToSheet("Sending a webhook to a URL: " + url);
  logToSheet("Webhook Options: " + JSON.stringify(payload));

  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  logToSheet("Response from webhook server: " + response.getContentText());
}

function testSendWebhook() {
  const newRowData = [
    "2023-04-04",
    "GA1.2.123456789.987654321",
    "test_source",
    "test_medium",
    "test_campaign",
    "test_term",
    "test_content",
  ];

  sendWebhook(WEBHOOK_URL, newRowData);
}

function logToSheet(logMessage) {
  const logSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName(LOGS_SHEET_NAME);
  const timestamp = new Date();
  logSheet.appendRow([timestamp, logMessage]);
}
```

I considered using the onEdit and onChange functions in Google Apps Script to automatically send a webhook when a row is added via an incoming request. However, these trigger functions are not suitable for this task, as they are only activated when a user manually edits cells or changes the sheet structure in Google Sheets. When a row is added via an incoming request, these functions are not triggered, and the webhook is not sent.

Instead of using onEdit and onChange, I tried to integrate the webhook sending function directly into the main incoming request handling code, but the automatic webhook sending still didn't work. Manually running the webhook sending function from the script editor(or via button from sheet) was successful, but automatic sending after adding a row via an incoming request was not performed.

I need help with modifying my code so that the webhook is sent automatically after adding a row to the Google Sheet on an incoming request. Thanks in advance!